# Eclipse - Implementing and incrementing an swt progress bar in toolbar

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, e4

I working on an application to parse data from a directory tree and while doing so have a progress monitor in the bottom toolbar displaying. I'm using java Files.walk() to walk the structure and have be trying to use IEventBroker, to send a message to the toolbar part to increment the progress bar, but his doesn't seem to be working well for me. Does anyone know of a better approach for this?

This is the code where the search begins and events broadcasted.

```
Path file = Paths.get(directoryPath);

    if (!file.toFile().exists())
    {
        return null;
    }

    _broker.send(Constants.INITIALISE_PROGRESS_BAR, file.toFile().list().length);

    try (final Stream<Path> pathStream = Files.walk(file))
    {
        pathStream.forEach(path ->
        {

            _broker.send(Constants.INCREMENT_PROGRESS_BAR, "inc");

            ........

        });

    }
```

In my toolbar section i have the following methods to intialise the maximum size of the progress and for incrementing when they receive an event.

```
@Inject
@Optional
private void initialiseProgressBar(@UIEventTopic(Constants.INITIALISE_PROGRESS_BAR) Integer max)
{
    _progressBar.setMinimum(0);
    _progressBar.setMaximum(max);

}

@Inject
@Optional
private void incrementProgressBar(@UIEventTopic(Constants.INCREMENT_PROGRESS_BAR) String path)
{
    incrementProgressBar();
}

private void incrementProgressBar()
{
    _progressBar.setSelection(_progressBar.getSelection() + 1);
}
```

Since I don't know the file structure size it might be best not increment but instead just have some sort of continious progress.

Comment: So is this an 'e4' RCP? For e4 IEventBroker should be fine, but you need to show us some code.

Comment: It is Greg, I'll post now in a sec.

Comment: So what is actually wrong with this?

Comment: Well it always seems to increment after the files have been parsed. For instance I've just been playing with JFace ProgressIndicator to show an animated progress, which suites my needs nicely, but when I initialise the indicator in my initialiseProgressBar() method, and use beginAnimatedTask(), it doesn't start straight away but after the parsing has finished.

Comment: Are you running the parsing in the main UI thread? - that will block the thread until you finish and the UI won't update. You must use a background thread, or Job or ProgressMonitorDialog for long running code

Comment: Your right I am using the main UI thread. I'll implement a background thread and see how I go then.

Answer (score 0):

One way (in addition to what proposed @greg-449) is to change the way you are firing the init/refresh events like this

```
@Inject
private UISynchronize       sync;
...
sync.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    _broker.send(Constants.INCREMENT_PROGRESS_BAR, "inc");            
  }
});
```

Comment: I've actually been trying this along with gregs answer but I'm still having an issue with this async not being called. It always updates the progress bar after the parsing of the files has finished.

Comment: Q: is the code you posted here before in the same class or in 2 different classes/instances?

Comment: Two separate classes. One broadcasts and other simply receives.